# VueFire: How to move this.$bind('photos') to component's global scope?

Tags: vuefire

I am using VueFire with Firebase. Can someone tell me where/how I can move `const documents = db.collection('photos').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')` to more of a global scope of my SFC ?

Right now I have it like:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import { db, photosCollection, storage } from '@/firebase'
export default {
  name: 'Photos',
  data() {
    return {
      photos: [],
      selected: 'all',
      options: [
        { text: 'All', value: 'all' },
        { text: 'Unsolved', value: 'unsolved' },
        { text: 'Solved', value: 'solved' }
      ]
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.allPhotos()
  },

  // // using vuefire here to make it easier to map data() to photo array
  // firestore() {
  //   return {
  //     photos: photosCollection.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  //   }
  // },

async allPhotos() {
      try {
        const documents = db.collection('photos').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        const test = await this.$bind('photos', documents)
        console.log('return anything?: ', test)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
```

I need to use the photos document collection in a few more methods within my SFC and don't want to keep typing `const documents = db.collection('photos').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')` all time. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think may be a viable solution:

```
async allPhotos() {
  try {
    // const documents = db.collection('photos').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
    const docs = await this.$bind('photos', photosCollection.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'))
    console.log('all photos: ', docs)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('problem sorting all photos: ', error)
  }
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, but seems to work good...